# Java Web Application Structure Set Welcome Page

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on Java after a long period of time so finding it hard to recall the things.

I configured an web application project in Netbeans like

```
WebApplication1
 - Web Pages
   - META-INF
   - WEB-INF
     - jsp (folder)
      - index.jsp
      - login.jsp
      - loginsuccess.jsp
     - applicationContext.xml (under WEB-INF)
     - dispatcher-servlet.xml (under WEB-INF)
     - web.xml (under WEB-INF)
   - redirect.jsp (under Web Pages)
```

Now in web.xml under welcome file list is

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I try to change redirect.jsp with jsp/login.jsp or login.jso under welcome file list it says 404.

Please suggest me best way to architect and how can I change this behavior if required.

Thanks

Comment: The contents of the WEB-INF folder are not accessible to a browser.

Comment: Remember that everything under WEB-INF is not directly accessible from a web browser. It's common practice for incoming requests to be handled by some servlet based controller which then forwards or includes WEB-INF/jsp/some.jsp.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180090/web-xml-welcome-file-from-web-inf-folder

Answer (score 0):

you are getting 404 because your `jsp folder` is inside `WEB-INF` and browser is not able to access web-inf due to security, keep your jsp folder under `root folder`.